# Record/Listen to audio of a specific windows/application using python/javascript like audacity or obs does it

Tags: javascript, python, audio

I want to record/listen to audio from a specific windows application, discord in my case, I want to know when people are talking in discord, and when they are, do some other thing, I have tried the discord APIs but they have their own issues, Audacity and OBS like programs can distinguish where the audio is coming from, I'm wondering if I can do the same with python